# high level planner package

Tags: ros, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a stack or package which handles high level behavior planner like [xabsl](http://www.xabsl.de/). I am expecting to find a simple finite state machine based behavior controller. If there is none, I am planning develop and I would appreciate any help from the community. I am also cruious about what the community uses for high level planning.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44141/high-level-planner-package/) by [Okan Aşık](https://answers.ros.org/users/3230/okan-a%C5%9F%C4%B1k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, SMACH, which stands for 'state machine', is a task-level architecture for rapidly creating complex robot behavior. At its core, SMACH is a ROS-independent Python library to build hierarchical state machines. [check out for detailed information](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach) hope it helps :D

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-19**:
Also, have a look at the [Cram Plan Language](http://ros.org/wiki/cram_language).